# Update the Counter in Badge, Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

I'm using this [Plugin.Badge](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge) to display cart items count on tabbed view in Xamarin Forms app.

here is my tabbed page xaml code **MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.Badge.Abstractions"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            SelectedTabColor="{StaticResource HighlightText}"  BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource HighlightBg}" UnselectedTabColor="Gray" 
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Projectname.Views" x:Class="Projectname.Views.MainPage" >
   <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Home" IconImageSource="home.png">
                  <x:Arguments>
                <views:HomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

         <NavigationPage Title="Search" IconImageSource="search.png">
            
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
         
         <NavigationPage Title="Cart" IconImageSource="cart.png" 
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgeText= "{Binding Counter}"  
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgeColor="Red"
              plugin:TabBadge.BadgeTextColor="White"   plugin:TabBadge.BadgePosition="PositionTopRight" >
           
            <x:Arguments>
              
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>


        <NavigationPage Title="Account" IconImageSource="account.png">
            
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AccountPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

below is the Code behind in **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

//using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;


namespace Projectname.Views
{
    
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]

    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        int Counter;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Counter = 2;
         }
     }
 }
```

In one of the tabbedpage children you can see, the badge is set like
plugin:TabBadge.BadgeText= ""{Binding Counter}"

**But is not working.**

I want to set the value of the badge counter to the value of variable in the code behind page  **MainPage.xaml.cs**

for that what all changes to be done in the code. Please help me on this.

Comment: Hi , you need to bind value in children page , not only in `MainPage`. You can have a look at the [sample code](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge/blob/master/Source/Sample/Plugin.Badge.Sample/Views/GenericBadgeTab.xaml). I'm not knowing why this not works in MainPage, maybe it's an issue for this NugetPackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. You are creating local variable and not even setting binding context.

First of all I recommend to create ViewModel for example:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Counter
    {
        set { counter = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Counter))); }
        get { return counter; }
    }

}
```

Then in your MainPage create binding context to viewmodel

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    private MainPageViewModel viewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.Counter = 2;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @adlorem, I'm trying to implement your code